# Change default app for customer portal profiles

Tags: customer-portal, administration, security, profile

I cannot uninstall an AppExchange application because it is the default app for the Customer Portal profiles.  However, when I try to edit these profiles, they are read-only with respect to the default app setting.  I did not have the customer portal feature enabled and nothing changed when I did enable that feature.  How do I change the default app setting for the Customer Portal profiles so I can then uninstall the app?

Comment: Web interface for Profiles sometimes isn't as accurate as it should be. Apologies in advance for a developer's approach if you're System Administrator and not a programmer... Can you download Profiles to Eclipse IDE or similar tool and check if they contain the `<applicationVisibilities>` tags you could edit?

Comment: Thanks eyescream.  Yes, that is a solution.  I have no idea how the org got in that state but editing the metadata allowed me to remove all dependencies on the application.  It was only the portal profiles that were a problem.

Comment: Hehe. Glad I helped, but I wouldn't call it a solution :) I got similar problem when I tried to deactivate & then delete some old Case record types - they turned out to be used by Customer Portal, Site Guest Users and even "External Who" (quick googling says "External Who" Profile is a leftover from courtesy licenses that might have been assigned to my employee in the past, WTF). Can't even shout at the previous admin for ticking all checkboxes, he's not with company anymore... This trick doesn't work on "Ext. Who", I'm supposed to ask SF Support for help :D